# JSON parsing using c# and LitJson

Tags: c#, litjson

I have a JSON data (file attached). How can I parse it using C# using LitJSON? I am having trouble in deserialising it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
"vr-sessions" : {
"-KvDNAFD_BxlKEJ958eX" : {
  "interview" : "Android",
  "questions" : {
    "-KvG7BuWu4eI52pq-6uH" : {
      "playaudio" : "audio1",
      "question" : "Why cannot you run standard Java bytecode on Android?"
    },
    "-KvG9rxQv5DWJa1EMnhi" : {
      "playaudio" : "audio2",
      "question" : "Where will you declare your activity so the system can access it?"
    }
  }
},
"-KvDNOE8YhVdgovxrzrN" : {
  "interview" : "DevOps",
  "questions" : {
    "-KvMPd0v9BXnjYZxFm5Q" : {
      "playaudio" : "audio3",
      "question" : "Explain what is DevOps?"
    },
    "-KvMPi24OKeQTp8aJI0x" : {
      "playaudio" : "audio4",
      "question" : "What are the core operations of DevOps with application development and with infrastructure?"
    },
    "-KvMPqYxJunKp2ByLZKO" : {
      "playaudio" : "audio5",
      "question" : "Explain how “Infrastructure of code” is processed or executed in AWS?"
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Your json doesn't seem to be valid. Provide a valid json.

Comment: @shaw it looks like he is only copying the first two objects of the json string.

Comment: Have you *tried* parsing it with LitJson? What happened? Please provide a [mcve] showing how far you've got, and what happened.

Comment: @vipersassassin You are right. There are many objects like that. Could not copy all here. Sorry for not closing the JSON with brackets at the end.

Comment: @ManishKumar post a proper sample, code and an explanation of the problem. Don't force people to *guess* what the question is. "What's wrong" isn't a question. Also provide a link to `LitJson`. Google returns links to an abandoned Github project. Why don't you use an up-to-date deserializer like Json.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding a couple of missing braces and removing last comma, your json seems to be valid. However there's no way to declare a class or member starting with dash in C#. Not sure how LitJson would be able to map json values to a C# class if names don't match, unless you replace dashes before parsing the string with LitJson.

**Workaround**

In your Solution Explorer right click `References` and do `Add Reference`, then from *Assemblies->Framework* select `System.Web.Extensions`.

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText("json.txt");
dynamic json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

**Navigate to the value you're looking for**

```
string interview = json["vr-sessions"]["-KvDNAFD_BxlKEJ958eX"]["interview"];
```

Variable `interview` gets value "Android" which is the same as doing this:

```
var sessions = json["vr-sessions"];
string interview = sessions["-KvDNAFD_BxlKEJ958eX"]["interview"];
```

**If you don't know session names**

Iterate to get question and playaudio values.

```
foreach (var session in json["vr-sessions"].Values)
{
    foreach (var question in session["questions"].Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(question["question"]);
        Console.WriteLine(question["playaudio"]);
    }
}
```

Access to an element by position: let's say you want to iterate 0..N

```
var sessions = new List<dynamic>(json["vr-sessions"].Values);
Console.WriteLine(sessions[0]["interview"]);
```

This prints "Android" as the value of interview for session at position 0 is "Android".

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I don't know "-KvDNAFD_BxlKEJ958eX" in advance. And there are many keys like that, around 100. How can I access "playaudio" or "question" in this scenario?

Comment: If you don't know session's name the only way to go is using a dynamic object like the above. I have updated my answer to show you how to iterate and get those values, ignoring session names.